# I can not understand why the data in the DB is not updated - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I use DB SQLite and I want to update the data, but when the data changes, nothing happens, only a warning pops up in the console (I attached it below). I tried different options, but still I can’t understand why I can’t update the data. Though create/delete works well without problems. And updating the data in the DB caused such difficulties. I would be grateful if you tell me what could be the reason.

**database**

```
 Future<int> updateTodo(Todo todo) async {
    Database db = await database;
    return await db
        .update(todoTable, todo.toMap(), where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [todo.id]);
  }
```

**edit_todo_screen**

```
class EditTodoScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Todo todo;
  EditTodoScreen({Key? key, required this.todo}) : super(key: key);

  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _controller.text = todo.description;

    return BlocBuilder<TodoBloc, TodoState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Edit Todo'),
        ),
        body: _body(context),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget _body(context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            autocorrect: true,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter todo message'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              BlocProvider.of<TodoBloc>(context).add(
                UpdateTodos(
                  todo,
                  _controller.text,
                ),
              );
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: _updateBtn(context),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**todo_bloc**

```
on<UpdateTodos>((event, emit) async {
  await todoRepository.updateTodo(event.todo);
  final List<Todo> _loadedTodoList = await todoRepository.getAllTodos();
  emit(TodoLoadedState(loadedUser: _loadedTodoList));
});
```

**todo_event**

```
class UpdateTodos extends TodoEvent {
  final Todo todo;

  const UpdateTodos(this.todo);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [todo];
}
```

**todo_list**

```
class TodoList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TodoList> createState() => _TodoListState();
}

class _TodoListState extends State<TodoList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BlocProvider.of<TodoBloc>(context).add(LoadTodos());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    BlocProvider.of<TodoBloc>(context).close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TodoBloc todoBloc = context.read<TodoBloc>();
    return BlocBuilder<TodoBloc, TodoState>(builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is TodoEmptyState) {
        return const Center(
          child: Text(
            'No Todo',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        );
      }

      if (state is TodoLoadingState) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      if (state is TodoLoadedState) {
        return ListView.builder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: state.loadedUser.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Column(children: [
                    Text('${state.loadedUser[index].description}'),
                    Text('${state.loadedUser[index].id}'),
                  ]),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      todoBloc.add(DeleteTodos(id: state.loadedUser[index].id));
                      // todoBloc.add(LoadTodos());
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => EditTodoScreen(
                                todo: Todo(
                                    description:
                                        '${state.loadedUser[index].description}'),
                              )),
                    );
```

**todo_model**

```
class Todo {
  int? id;
  late String description;
  // bool isDone = false;

  Todo({this.id, required this.description});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['id'] = id;
    map['description'] = description;
    // map['isDone'] = isDone == false ? 0 : 1;
    return map;
  }

  Todo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map['id'];
    description = map['description'];
    // isDone = map['isDone'] == 0 ? false : true;
  }
}
```

**todo_repository**

```
class TodoRepository {
  final db = DBProvider();

  Future getAllTodos() => db.getTodos();

  Future insertTodo(Todo todo) => db.createTodo(todo);

  Future updateTodo(Todo todo) => db.updateTodo(todo);

  Future deleteTodo(int id) => db.deleteTodo(id);

  Future deleteAllTodo(int id) => db.deleteAllTodo(id);
}
```

When I click on the button, this is the warning in the console

[image]

Comment: Could you include the code to your `Todo` class as well?

Comment: Okey, turned on

Comment: No I meant the `Todo` model, the one you pass to `updateTodo` and has id, description, etc.

Comment: Understood, added :)

Answer (score 1):

```
return await db
        .update(todoTable, todo.toMap(), where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [todo.id]);
```

The error you're getting happens here because todo id is null. This is what you're doing when routing to `EditTodoScreen`:

```
Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => EditTodoScreen(
          todo: Todo(
            description: '${state.loadedUser[index].description}',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Notice the todo here:

```
todo: Todo(
      description: '${state.loadedUser[index].description}',
),
```

You're only passing description, but no id. This is why you get that error when trying to update.

You already have access to the todo you're trying to update so you can just pass that instead of creating a new one. Use this code for routing to `EditTodoScreen`:

```
Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => EditTodoScreen(
          todo: state.loadedUser[index],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: When I change the routing, the data still does not update, is it possible that the problem is now in the EditTodoScreen itself? It is at the moment when I click on the Update button?

Comment: @MaxZubko Does it still give Invalid argument warning?

Comment: Yes, same error as before. changed in todo_list to what you wrote (passing id) but still an error

Comment: @MaxZubko Interesting. From what I can see it seems everything should be ok. Add a print statement at the start of your `updateTodo` method `print("${todo.id}");` and see if it's null or not. Then keep going back until you find where is it that you lose access to id. Because in your `TodoList` you are using `state.loadedUser[index].id` to delete and you stated in quesion that delete works. So whatever the problem is should be further down the line.

Comment: @MaxZubko Also this is the event you're adding to bloc: `UpdateTodos(todo, _controller.text)`. But the `UpdateTodos` event only has a todo of class `Todo`. There is no second argument for the constructor. Is there another `UpdateTodos`?

Comment: no, just one UpdateTodos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241101/discussion-between-ramin-and-max-zubko).